# jQuery UI close Dialog when form submitted

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, dialog, modal-dialog

I have been trying to do the follow:

- Form gets showed inside jQuery Dialog
- When form gets submitted, jQuery dialog should close

I am trying the following code:

```
    $('#RegisterDialog').dialog({
               autoOpen: false,
                closeOnEscape: false,
                position: 'center',
                modal: true,
                width: 600,
                buttons: {
                    "Cancel account registration": function() { 
                        $(this).dialog("close"); 
                        window.location = 'http://localhost/';
                    } 
                }
});

$(".Register").click(function() {
           $('#RegisterDialog').dialog("close"); 
           $('#RegisterDialog').hide();
});
```

However, it hides and pops back up again. I also tried 'autoClose: false'.

Any help please?

Comment: Hmmm, just a note. This gets executed on document load. Could that be a problem?

When the form gets executed, it makes a query to the same page.

Comment: Currently you have autoOpen: false, and dialog should not pop up after page loaded. Then how do you show your dialog, where is the $('#RegisterDialog').dialog("open"); triggered?

Answer (score 1):

You should try `.remove()`.

This will remove the element and it won't pop up again.

Answer (score 0):

From the jQuery documentation...

```
.dialog( "destroy" ) 
// Remove the dialog functionality completely. This will return the element back to its pre-init state.
```

This might do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do like this

```
$(".Register").click(function() {
           $('#RegisterDialog').dialog("close"); 
           //$('#RegisterDialog').hide(); --> no need to call this
});
```

Comment: Just tried it; doesn't work. I also tried .dialog("destroy") and that doesn't  work either. It goes away for a second and comes back right away. Something keeps triggering it to come back up it seems